# Calculating integral over manifold given by equations

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, multiple-integral

> Describe the area of the following manifold: $M=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2=f(z)^2, 0\lt z \lt 1\}$, as a one dimensional integral.

My attempt -

I define $F(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-f(z)^2$ and therefore $M=\{(x,y,z)| F(x,y,z) = 0\}$.

The formula(as much as I know) for such defintion of manifolds over $\mathbb{R}^3$ is: $\int_M dA = \int F(x,y,z)\frac{\sqrt{|\nabla F|}}{|F_z|}dxdydz$.

In our case: $F_z = -2f(z)f'(z)$, and $|\nabla F|= |4x^2+4y^2+4f(z)^2f'(z)^2|$.

Putting it all together: $\int_M dA = \int_0^1\int_0^{f(z)^2}\int_0^{f(z)^2} (x^2+y^2-f(z)^2)\frac{\sqrt{|4x^2+4y^2+4f(z)^2f'(z)^2|}}{|-2f(z)f'(z)|}dxdydz$

But I'm really not sure how to continue from here... Any hints?

Or perhaps, is there any way doing it using some parameterization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to cylinder coordinates gives $r^2 = f(z)^2$, so $r = |f(z)|, z\in(0,1), \theta \in [0,2\pi]$. Your surface is then composed of horizontal strips (perpendicular to the $z$-axis) of thickness $dz$, radius $r(z) = |f(z)|$, and hence area $2\pi |f(z)| dz$. So the total area would be

$$
A = 2 \pi \int_0^1 |f(z)| dz
$$

Comment: But how can we just switch to cylinder coordinates, without knowing how will it affect $z$?

Comment: $z$ doesn't get affected: $x=r\cos\theta,\; y=r\sin\theta,\; z=z$.